# What is the angular way of binding a directive inside another directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a directive which will be used to establish client and server-side validation on an input. It should accept an array of validator names (e.g. `aa-validate="required,unique"`), loop through them, add client-side validation directives for all possible validators (e.g. `required` should add `ngRequired`), and for the rest, post to a server-side validation API.

The last part of that works well: I am watching the `ngModel` attribute, and posting to the server with a 100ms timeout. However, setting client-side validation directives from within the linking function of my directive does NOT cause them to be compiled and linked. In other words, they do nothing. Here is my code:

```
angular.module('form', [])
    .directive('aaValidate', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            priority: 1,
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var validate = attrs.aaValidate,
                    validators = validate.split(',');

                // This is the problem!
                //
                // Populate possible client-side validators
                for (var i = 0, len = validators.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var validator = validators[i];
                    switch (validator) {
                        case 'required':
                            attrs.$set('ngRequired', 'true'); break;
                        // ... and so on for ngPattern, etc.
                        default: break;
                    }
                }

                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                    // This part works!
                    //
                    // Clear existing timeout, reset it with an
                    // $http.post to my validation API, the result is
                    // passed into ctrl.$setValidity
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

I did make an attempt to inject `$compile`, and re-compile the element at the end of the linking function. I ended up with infinite recursion, likely because I failed to remove some attributes, but even if I manage to do it this way, it feels rather ugly. What is the correct approach?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nUdj/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer was wrong - I don't think there's any way around using the `$compile` service. Here's how you can do it without getting infinite recursion. I basically split the directive in two directives - one adds the validation directives, removes itself and recompiles. The other does the other stuff:

```js
angular.module('form', [])
.directive('aaValidate', ['$http', '$compile', function ($http, $compile) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var validate = attrs.aaValidate,
          validators = validate.split(',');

      // Populate possible front-end validators
      for (var i = 0, len = validators.length; i < len; i++) {
        var validator = validators[i];
        switch (validator) {
          case 'required':
            attrs.$set('ngRequired', 'true');
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
      attrs.$set('aaOther', '');
      element.removeAttr('aa-validate');
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  }
}])

.directive('aaOther', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
          // Server-side validation
        });
      }
    }
});
```

You have to recompile the linked element for this to work in ng-repeat. I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nUdj/7/

Comment: Hi @joakimbl, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately this still does not work. I placed a `console.log` inside the `ngRequired` linking function and discovered that it is never called.

Comment: I did try placing the problem code into the pre-compile, pre-link, and post-link stage with no success.

Comment: Ok, do you think you could provide a plunker / jsfiddle?

Comment: Edited the question with a jsFiddle link. As you can see, deleting the text in the input does not cause `myForm.value.$valid` to become `false`

Comment: I think you have to use $compile - I've made an update to show you how you can avoid infinite recursion